# Почему вылезает ошибка c2280?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xml, классы

Задача следующая: Реализовать c++ объект, который предоставил бы возможность менять тип данных во время исполнения. Хранение значения типа данных должно храниться с использованием xml.Тут должны поддерживаться операции преобразования типов между "однотипными" данными;
Операции между типами данных, которые не согласуются между собой должны вызывать исключения.
Т.е. например: 
ten+P= 13;
twenty+str исключение

header.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

ofstream xml;

class Object {
public:
    ifstream fin;
    string path = "xml.txt";
    template <typename T>
    Object(T);
    Object();
    ~Object();
    template <typename T, typename T1, typename T2>
    Object(T, T1, T2);
    template < typename T > 
    Object operator + (T);
private:
    int num;
    int& Count();
    template <typename T>   
    void value(T);
    void open();    
    void close();
    string type;

};




void Object::open(){
    char buff[3];
    num = ++Count();
    _itoa_s(num, buff, 10);
    xml << "<" << buff << ">\n";
}

void Object::close() {
    char buff[3];
    _itoa_s(num, buff, 10);
    xml << "</" << buff << ">\n\n\n\n";
}

template <typename T>
void Object::value(T buff) {
    type = typeid(buff).name();
    if (type == "char const *") {type = "string";};
    xml << "<" << type << ">\n";
    xml << "<value>\n";
    xml << buff << "\n";
    xml << "</value>\n";
    xml << "</" << type << ">\n";
}

Object::Object() {
    open(); 
    close();
}

template <typename T>
Object::Object(T buff) {
    fin.open(path);
    open();
    value(buff);
    close();
    fin.close();

};

template <typename T, typename T1, typename T2>
Object :: Object(T buff1, T1 buff2, T2 buff3){
    fin.open(path);
    open();
    value(buff1);
    xml << "\n";
    value(buff2);
    xml << "\n";
    value(buff3);
    xml << "\n";
    close();
    fin.close();
}

int& Object::Count() {
    static int c = 0;
    return c;
}

Object :: ~Object() {
    --Count();
    xml.close();
}

template <typename T>
Object operator+(T &sum)
{
    try {
        if (typeid(value).name != typeid(sum.value))
            throw 666;
    }
    return T(this->value + sum.value);
    catch (int i){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#pragma once

int main() {

    ifstream fin;
    xml.open("xml.txt");
    Object arr(120, 23.5, "Word");
    Object arr1(1, 2, 3);
    Object arr2(15.5, 25.2, 22.3);
    Object ten = 10;
    Object twenty = 20;
    Object P = 3.14;
    Object str = "Course";
    Object str1 = "Program";
    Object boolean = false;
    Object boo = true;
    Object st("Hello!", "World", "WoW!");
    Object sum;
    sum = ten + P;


    return 0;
    }
```

У меня выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    1   error C2280:
>   "std::basic_ifstream>::basic_ifstream(const
>   std::basic_ifstream> &)": предпринята
>   попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию   c:\users\user\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\projects\course\course\main.cpp   25  1   course В месте
>
> sum = ten + P;

Помогите разобраться, как её исправить, что бы все работало?

Comment: В операторе + ошибка -  sum.value, а sum.value - не обьявено, поэтому невозможно собрать template так как *поле* или *свойство* с именем value отсутствует в вашем object.

Comment: Разве sum.value не является (T &sum)?

Comment: Нет. Потому что T в вашем случае Object, у которого value это функция, а функцию так нельзя использовать.

Comment: Ну и ошибка, насколько я понимаю, не в этом, а именно в самом конструкторе operator+(T &sum)

Comment: Как сделать так, что бы работало?

Comment: эти две ошибки между собой связаны - это особенность обобщений. Или всё должно соответствовать шаблону Т, или то что не соответствует - не должно быть при Т.

Comment: Нужно объявить новую переменную вместо value?

Comment: А мне не понятно почему `void value(Т)` используется как переменная. Возможно нужно создать другую value с другим именем, а возможно это "логическая" ошибка, и нужно пересмотреть работу класса вообще.

Comment: Эта функция для другого нужна просто, что бы определить тип переменной и записать в файл

Comment: Тогда не используйте тут value.

Comment: Да, я уже взял другую переменную, но ошибку все равно выдает

Comment: Только теперь другая, я взял другую переменную типа T, выдает ошибку: "Ошибка 1 error C3857: Object::value1: множественные списки параметров шаблон не допускаются"

Comment: Что такое value1, откуда оно возьмется. Вот в этом и основной вопрос. У вас тип value1, а неопределенность нельзя записать, отобразить. value1 который вы хотите вернуть должно иметь конкретный тип.

Answer (score 2):

`sum = ten + P;` выполняет вызов неявно сгенерированного копирующего оператора присваивания, который будет копировать все поля класса, включая `fin`, однако объекты `ifstream` являются некопируемыми. Однако они могут быть перемещены. Соответственно для своего класса следует реализовать перемещающий оператор присваивания (и перемещающий конструктор за одно). Однако в данном случае на самом деле нет никакого смысла держать `fin` среди полей класса, так как он используется исключительно как локальная переменная.

Comment: Как это реализовать? Можете помочь?

Comment: я бы  хранил в классе ссыльку, а не обьект ifstream.  Это, думаю,  было бы логичней

Comment: @ARHovsepyan При хранении в классе ссылки реализовать полноценный оператор присваивания было бы невозможно, так как ссылки нельзя ребиндить.

Comment: @VTT,  ребиндить нельзя, но нужно ли ?  А впрочем вы правы: имеется ввиду также последнее предложение вашего ответа...

Comment: Подскажите как реализовать перемещающий оператор присваивания и перемещающий конструктор в данном коде

Comment: @user300594 Они реализуются простым перемещением каждого поля.

Comment: Через getline что ли?

Comment: @user300594 Загляните в [справочник](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)